# increasing rosserial's publishing rate for Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm using ROS to control my cable-robot. I use Arduinos to create communication between ROS and sensors and actuators. But, frequency of rosserial_python node is low (120 hz) and because of that the system is not controlled well. Is there any other nodes or boards that I can use for my project?

Thank you in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223433/increasing-rosserial%27s-publishing-rate-for-arduino/) by [soheilred](https://answers.ros.org/users/5280/soheilred/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-03**:
You've edited this question twice in the last hour, without actually adding new data. Updating your question this frequently pushes down questions from other users, and isn't likely to actually get an answer more quickly.

**Comment by [soheilred](https://answers.ros.org/users/5280/soheilred/) on 2016-01-04**:
I edited the title, which seems is not shown in the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.shadowrobot.com/products/ronex/ for example will give you much more regular updates

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [soheilred](https://answers.ros.org/users/5280/soheilred/) on 2016-01-04**:
Thank you for your answer.
It is written in the website that "RoNeX sends and receives data packets 1,000 times a second, consistently, all the time." Does it mean that no matter how many sensor we connect, it will publish the data in rate of 1 Khz?

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-01-06**:
my understanding is that the module will be able to read all its gpios and send values in that time. As you add more modules you might saturate the bandwidth of the bus, but as it is ethernet you would need to add a lot of modules before that happened, but you could get clarification from them

**Comment by [soheilred](https://answers.ros.org/users/5280/soheilred/) on 2016-01-07**:
Thank you for your answer.